# Button press create/replace new window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwidget, qwizard

**Goal:**

I have an initial window, with 4 choices represented by buttons. When the user clicks on the button, the window content should be cleared (eg. all the buttons should dissapear), and replaced by new content (could be another button, a text field,...)

**Current code:**

```
import sys
import PyQt5
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QApplication, QWidget, QStackedWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QIcon, QPixmap, QPalette, QFont

class QWizard(QtWidgets.QWizard):
    def __init__(self):        
        super().__init__()
        self.init_window()
        self.initial_options()

    def init_window(self):
        self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.setWizardStyle(QtWidgets.QWizard.ModernStyle)
        self.setWindowTitle("TILE")
        self.setMinimumSize(800,600)

        self.page1 = QtWidgets.QWizardPage()
        self.font = QFont()
        self.font.setWeight(QFont.Bold)
        self.page1.setTitle('INTRO TITLE')
        self.page1.setSubTitle('SUBTITLE')


    def initial_options(self):
        b1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("BUTTON 1")
        b1.setFont(self.font)
        b1.setMinimumSize(100,100)
        b1.clicked.connect(self.b1_clicked)

        b2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("BUTTON 2")
        b2.setFont(self.font)
        b2.setMinimumSize(100,100)

        b3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("BUTTON 3")
        b3.setFont(self.font)
        b3.setMinimumSize(100,100)

        b4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("BUTTON 4")
        b4.setFont(self.font)
        b4.setMinimumSize(100,100)

        hLayout1 = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.page1)

        hLayout1.addRow(b1)
        hLayout1.addRow(b2)
        hLayout1.addRow(b3)
        hLayout1.addRow(b4)

        self.addPage(self.page1)
        self.show()

    def b1_clicked(self):
        print("CLICKED BUTTON 1 - CREATE NEW/FRESH SWINDOW")
        self.b1_click = QtWidgets.QWizardPage()
        font = QFont()
        font.setWeight(QFont.Bold)
        self.b1_click.setTitle('TITLE OF NEW WINOW')
        self.b1_click.setSubTitle('DO SOMETHING IN THIS WINDOW')

        self.addPage(self.b1_click)
        self.show


App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWizard()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

**Output:**

[image: Output generated from the code, without clicking on any button]

When button 1 is clicked, all the buttons should dissapear, the titles should be changed,... Everything should be new.

2 options to fix this come to mind:

- Replace the initial window (destroy it, hide it,...) with the new one.
- Create different widgets for every button / title, and hide it when clicking the button. QStackedWidgets / QStackedLayout come to mind but I have troubles implementing it in my code

Comment: You already have the solutions, in my opinion the best is to use QStackedWidget, what is your problem?

Comment: For some reason I just can't get it to work for my example, using the buttons.

Comment: Where in your code do you use QStackedWidget?

Comment: I just got it to work. I will update my code with the solution soon!